# Find results of query executed in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I know this might sound weird and practically impossible. But just wanted to reach to check on any options.

I had a couple of tables truncated and now I used `F8` to retrieve the last executed results. But I want to see the **Query results** as well. Is there a way to see that?

Comment: Huh?  If you truncated the table, the data is gone.

Comment: Yes. Guessed that. Hmm